# Is there any way the JSON comparison ignores the whole section misplaced?

Tags: ruby, json, cucumber

I am trying to compare two JSON objects. When a 'key:value' pair order changes, I can use `JSON.parse`, and during comparison, the test passes like this:

```
doc1 = '{
    "KayA": "Value_A",
    "KeyB": "value_B"
}'

doc2 = '{
    "KeyB": "value_B",
    "KayA": "Value_A"
}'

doc1 = JSON.parse(doc1)
doc2 = JSON.parse(doc2)

expect(doc1).to eq(doc2) # true
```

But when the order of a section, an array, or a block of content changes, my assertion fails if I do the same comparison logic like below:

```
doc1 = '{
    "keys": [
        {
            "KayA": "Value_A",
            "KeyB": "value_B"
        },
        {
            "KayC": "Value_C",
            "KeyD": "value_D"
        }
    ]
}'

doc2 = '{
    "keys": [
        {
            "KayC": "Value_C",
            "KeyD": "value_D"
        },
        {
            "KayA": "Value_A",
            "KeyB": "value_B"
        }
    ]
}'

doc1 = JSON.parse(doc1)
doc2 = JSON.parse(doc2)

expect(doc1).to eq(doc2) # false
```

Is there anyway I can compare even if a block changes?

Comment: `Array` equality cares about order. e.g. `['a','b','c'] == ['c','b','a'] #=> false` this is explicitly defined in both `==` and `eql?` in the `Array` Documentation.(Array passes sets like `'a'` and `'c'` to determine equality) `Hash` equality cares that the `keys` are the same and the values for those keys are the same. (Hash checks the keys and then passes the keys to each to check the values)  So the answer to your question of is there a way is yes but you would have to create it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that hashes and arrays have different ideas of equality. Consider these:

```
{a:1, b:2} == {a:1, b:2} # => true
{a:1, b:2} == {b:2, a:1} # => true

[1,2] == [1,2] # => true
[1,2] == [2,1] # => false
```

Once the equality check hits the embedded arrays, Ruby sees that the arrays don't match and says so.

It doesn't matter how far into the structure you look, you'll still get the same result unless you can determine on your own that one array is the same as the other.