# how to make cucumber throw exception with RED color in test results

Tags: ruby, json, cucumber

this is based on my previous question here [Is there any way the JSON comparison ignores the whole section misplaced?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32747080/is-there-any-way-the-json-comparison-ignores-the-whole-section-misplaced).

I have written a logic to compare two json ignoring the array or block order changes(might not be a best solution, but it works). But though it compares, as i validate with user written code with 'if..else' statement, when the cucumber completes the test & outputs the results, it throws always GREEN in the results file. So unable for user to decide the test actually passed or failed. Typicall when i run the cucumber with the below statement for compare, the results will show in RED color if the test fails with exception.

```
expect(doc1).to eq(doc2)
```

Could someone help on how to make the cucumber throws exception or any cucmber failure with RED color for the failed test in the results with the below comparison logic.

```
require 'json'

doc1 = '{
    "keys": [
        {
            "KayA": "Value_A",
            "KeyB": "value_B"
        },
        {
            "KayC": "Value_C",
            "KeyD": "value_D"
        }
    ]
}'

doc2 = '{
    "keys": [
        {
            "KayC": "Value_C",
            "KeyD": "value_D"
        },
        {
            "KayA": "Value_A",
            "KeyB": "value_B"
        }
    ]
}'

doc1 = JSON.parse(doc1)
doc2 = JSON.parse(doc2)

puts "doc1 : #{doc1}"
puts "doc2 : #{doc2}"

#puts "values....: #{doc1}"

@final_array = Array.new

doc1.each { |k, v|
  @doc1_key = k
  @doc1_value = v
  #puts @doc1_key
  #puts @doc1_value
  @doc1_array_size = @doc1_value.size
  puts "@doc1_array_size...: #{@doc1_array_size}"
  @doc1_value.each { |lhsval|
    puts "fresh start first loop......"
    puts "lhsval...: #{lhsval}"
    doc2.each { |act_k, act_v|
        @doc2_key = act_k
        @doc2_value = act_v
        #puts @doc2_key
        #puts @doc2_value
        puts "fresh start second loop......"
        @doc2_value.each { |rhsval|
          puts "rhsval...: #{rhsval}"
            if lhsval == rhsval then
              #puts "This #{lhsval} is same as #{rhsval}"
              break
            else
              puts "This #{lhsval} is not same as #{rhsval}"
              @final_array << lhsval
            end
        }
    }
  }
}

puts "@final_array size is ...: #{@final_array.size}"

if @final_array.size == @doc1_array_size then
  puts "Two JSON objects are mismatching....."
else
  puts "Both the documents are same...."
end
```

Comment: any help is appreciated..

Comment: If the answers in your previous question solved your problem, remember to accept them. If they did not, you should post your own solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to force a cucumber scenario to fail?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11797171/how-to-force-a-cucumber-scenario-to-fail)

Comment: `@final_array = [ ]` is almost always preferable to the much more verbose `Array.new`. Same goes for `{ }` vs. `Hash.new`.